# Taylor series of ln(1/(1-z)) around 0

Tags: taylor-expansion

One more taylor/maclurian series problem to which I know the answer of, I just have no idea how to get there (This is as a formal power series, so convergence is not an issue)

$$\log \left(\frac 1 {1-z}\right)=\sum _{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 kz^k$$.
I've tried playing around with rewriting $\frac 1 {1-z}$  as $1+\frac z {1-z}$ and using the taylor expansion for $\log (1+z)$, but I can't seem to figure out what to do with all those powers in the denominator that show up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the Taylor expansion for $$\log (1-z).$$
So
$$\log \frac{1}{1-z}=-\log (1-z)=-\left(-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^k}{k} \right)=\sum _{{k=1}}^{+\infty}\frac{z^k}{k}.$$

Answer (score 11):

**Hint**

$$\log \left(\frac 1 {1-z}\right)=-\log(1-z)$$ Now consider the series for $\log(1+x)$ and make $x=-z$ in the result and you will be done.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP indicates that they know the series for $\log(1+x)$, so this seems a good answer.

Comment: Doh,  I'm an idiot and sleep deprived.  Thanks :).   gave this one an upvote and the other one the check

Comment: @Alan. You are not an idiot since you asked the question and, for me, there is no stupid question (stupid answers, yes). If I had be given one dollar each time I missed something obvious, I probably should be a billionaire ! Don't worry. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : $\displaystyle \int (1-x)^{-1}\,dx =-\log(1-x) $ .Now use the series expansion of $(1-x)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z)=\log\frac{1}{1-z} \implies f(0) = 0\\
f'(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} \implies f'(0) = 1\\
f^{(2)}(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} \implies \frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!} = \frac{1}{2}\\
f^{(3)}(z) = \frac{2!}{(1-z)^3} \implies \frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!} = \frac{1}{3}\\
\dots\\
f^{(n)}(z) = \frac{(n-1)!}{(1-z)^n} \implies \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} = \frac{1}{n}\\
$$

Comment: $f'(z)$ is not calculated correctly...

Comment: $f'(z) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1-z}}\frac{-1}{(1-z)^2}(-1)=\frac{1}{1-z}$

Comment: You're missing one minus somewhere.

Comment: It looks OK to me. I think @5xum misses a minus somewhere.

Comment: [We have the technology.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+log%281%2F%281-z%29%29)